# Hiding member functions in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, hide, sfinae

Is it possible to hide some member functions in a template class?
Let's imagine we have something like:

```
template <class T>
class Increment
{
public:
    void init(T initValue)
    {
         mValue = initValue;
    }  

    T increment()
    {
        ++mValue;
    }

    T increment(T delta)
    {
        mValue += delta;
    }
private:
    T mValue;
};
```

The objective is to use this class in a way that, in certain cases
we only see the increment() function and in some other cases
we only see the increment(T) member function.
To do that, I can think about something with SFINAE:

```
class MultipleIncrement
{
    typedef int MultipleIncrement_t;
};

class SingleIncrement
{
    typedef int SingleIncrement_t;
};

template <class T, class Q>
class Increment
{
public:
    void init(T initValue)
    {
        mValue = initValue;
    }

    T increment(typename Q::SingleIncrement_t = 0)
    {
        ++mValue;
    }

    T increment(T delta, typename Q::MultipleIncrement_t = 0)
    {
        mValue += delta;
    }
private:
    T mValue;
}
```

And then use my template like, for example:

```
Increment<long, MultipleIncrement>
```

However, the compiler is not letting me do this.
Is there any other way in which this is feasible?
Would it also work if the member function is actually the constructor?

Comment: Out of interest what compiler are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I would prefer using template specialization. Would something like this help you?

```
struct SingleIncrement;
struct MultipleIncrement;

template <
    class T, 
    class Policy = SingleIncrement // default template param
>
class Increment
{
    T mValue;
public:
    Increment(T initValue)
    :   mValue(initValue)
    {}

    T increment()
    {
        ++mValue;
    }
};

// template specialization for MultipleIncrement
template <class T>
class Increment<T,MultipleIncrement>
{
    T mValue;
public:
    Increment(T initValue)
    :   mValue(initValue)
    {}

    T increment(T delta)
    {
        mValue += delta;
    }
};
```

Comment: It is indeed an aproach; the problem is that "init" is not the only member function that must be initialized; quite the opposite, there are a lot of common functions that would be repeated, unless I start thinking about inheritance...

Comment: I would try to make use of inheritance to avoid reimplementing common function and then use template specialization to use orthogonal types.

Comment: Template specialization for MultipleIncrement would be declared like this: `template<class T> class Increment<T,MultipleIncrement> {...}`

Answer (score 1):

Template specialization is good.  Inheritance sounds better.  Have you considered templating on the inherited base class?  (Or is this now considered a faux pax?)

```
#define SHOW(X)  cout << # X " = " << (X) << endl

template <class T>
class A
{
public:
  void foo(T t) {SHOW(t); }
};

template <class T, class BASE>
class B : public BASE
{
public:
  void bar(T t) {SHOW(t); }
};

int
main()
{
  B<int,A<int> > b;
  b.foo(1);
  b.bar(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a MWE of how this could be achieved:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct multi;
struct single;

template<class T, class Q>
struct dummy {
  dummy(T value) : m_value(value) { }

  // using enable_if_t in template argument
  template<class _Q = Q, enable_if_t<is_same<_Q, single>::value && is_same<_Q, Q>::value, int> = 1>
  T increment() { return ++m_value; }

  // using enable_if_t in method return type
  template<class _Q = Q>
  enable_if_t<is_same<_Q, multi>::value && is_same<_Q, Q>::value, T>
  //enable_if_t<is_same<_Q, multi>::value, T> // (*)
  increment(T delta) { return (m_value += delta); }

  T m_value;
};

int main() {
  dummy<double, multi> m(47.10);
  //cout << m.increment() << endl; // error as expected
  cout << m.increment(.01) << endl;

  dummy<int, single> s(41);
  cout << s.increment() << endl;
  cout << s.increment<single>() << endl;
  //cout << s.increment(1) << endl; // error as expected
  //cout << s.increment<multi>(1) << endl; // not an error when using (*)
}
```

### Output

Using `c++ (Debian 6.2.1-5) 6.2.1 20161124` this yields:

```
47.11
42
43
```

### Elaboration

We need to template the methods to make SFINAE work at all. We cannot use something like

```
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<_Q, multiple_increment>::value, T> increment() ...
```

because that fails when **instantiating** the template `dummy<T, single_increment>` instead of failing when **substituting** method template parameters.

Further, we want the user to be able to use the methods without actually providing a method template parameter. So we make the method template parameter `_Q` default to `Q`.

Finally, to really force a compiler error when using the unwanted method even when providing a method template parameter, we only `enable_if_t` the method if method template parameter `_Q` is actually the same type as the respective class template parameter `Q`.